# Why was the Ghostface mask changed in the TV series?

Tags: production, costume, scream, scream-tv

Why was the [Father Death mask](http://scream.wikia.com/wiki/Father_Death_costume) of Ghostface

[image]

changed in the TV series [Scream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scream_(TV_series)) to a new one:

[image]

What is the reason for this change? The older one seemed to be more popular and loved, while the newer one seems less dramatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MTV exec Mina Lefevre explained

> It’s a darker, almost more grounded, evolved version of the mask It’s something we’re constantly talking about. How did that mask become that mask? What’s its purpose? How did it evolve? If the Scream movie mask was the more plastic version, for a lack of a better description, this one is a more organic looking and frankly darker version.The mask was a big discussion creatively. We wanted to get a nod and a wink to what the original was, but we definitely wanted to make it more on par with what horror is now, which is darker.

[More...](http://www.slashfilm.com/scream-tv-series-mask/)